Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
Ksql Db was starting absolutely fine up until now when I ran into this issue. I am aware that port on to which ksqldb starts shouldn't be occupied by any other process, so that's not an issue.
Anyway, here is the latest entry of the ksql log file.
[2024-05-19 16:01:12,622] ERROR Failed to start KSQL (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain:104)
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
    at java.base/java.lang.System.setSecurityManager(System.java:430)
    at io.confluent.ksql.function.UserFunctionLoader.newInstance(UserFunctionLoader.java:158)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.loadFunctions(KsqlServerMain.java:136)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.main(KsqlServerMain.java:88)


What version of Java is it using? Anything higher than 17 isn't supported

It is Java 11 lts.
